# window not defined error when using extract-text-webpack-plugin React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack to build my react components and I'm trying to use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to separate my css from my generated js file. However, when I attempt to build the component I get the following error:
`Module build failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    MainComponent: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'MainComponent',
    path: './build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader!css-loader')
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ]
}
```

Comment: i figured out the answer. rather than `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader!css-loader')` you have to write `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')`

Comment: Can you convert that to an answer and mark the problem solved? Thanks.

Comment: I just did. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 60):

You may want to use `style-loader` as a `before` argument in `extract` function.

Here's the native implementation:

```
    ExtractTextPlugin.extract = function(before, loader, options) {
        if(typeof loader === "string") {
            return [
                ExtractTextPlugin.loader(mergeOptions({omit: before.split("!").length, extract: true, remove: true}, options)),
                before,
                loader
            ].join("!");
        } else {
            options = loader;
            loader = before;
            return [
                ExtractTextPlugin.loader(mergeOptions({remove: true}, options)),
                loader
            ].join("!");
        }
    };
```

So basicaly what you need to do is:

```
{
    test: /\.sass$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css!sass?indentedSyntax=true&sourceMap=true')
},
```

if you for example use `sass`.

Comment: This resolved for me working with Stylus too. Thanks @squixy!

Comment: If you are having issue with scss not sass, then remove the indentedSyntax=true

Answer (score 43):

Didn't see an explanation of the cause so I have posted this answer here.

From https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#api

> `ExtractTextPlugin.extract([notExtractLoader], loader, [options])`
>   Creates an extracting loader from an existing loader.
>
> `notExtractLoader` (optional) the loader(s) that should be used when the css is not extracted (i.e. in an > additional chunk when allChunks: false)
>
> `loader` the loader(s) that should be used for converting the resource to a css exporting module.
>
> `options`
>
> `publicPath` override the publicPath setting for this loader.

The `#extract` method should receive a loader that outputs `css`. What was happening was that it was receiving a `style-loader` which outputs *javascript code*, which is intended to be injected into a webpage. This code would try to access `window`.

You should not pass a loader string with `style` to `#extract`. However...if you set `allChunks=false`, then it will not build CSS files for non-initial chunks. Therefore it needs to know what loader to use to inject into the page.

Tip: Webpack is a tool that really needs to be understood in-depth or you can run into lots of strange issues.

Comment: Best things I've ever heard about webpack.

Comment: sorry about not having an explanation in my answer. The webpack docs were still being written (and may still be) at the time I posted the question and answer. But I agree that it does need to be pretty well understood.

Comment: High quality content here. If the docs were half as good as this, I'd be a really happy programmer.

Answer (score 20):

## Webpack 2

If you're using Webpack 2, this variation works:

```
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: [{
                loader: 'style-loader',
            }],
            use: [{
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                },
            }, {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
            }],
        }),
    }]
```

The new extract method no longer takes three arguments, and is listed as a breaking change when moving from V1 to V2.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#extracttextwebpackplugin-breaking-change

Answer (score 12):

I figured out the solution to my problem:

Instead of piping the loaders into one another (`ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader!css-loader')`), you have to pass in the each loader as a separate parameter: `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')`

Comment: Pretty sure this is what @squixy said to do 5 months prior.

Comment: The statement "each loader as a separate parameter" is true only for two loaders, and is wrong for three or more. The `extract` function takes three parameters: `(before, loader, options)`, and this answer covers that perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30982133/1346510

Comment: @sompylasar thank you so much for this comment. It has solved my issue! I assumed all the params passed in would just be straight looped through. Happy to say that if you need to use `'style', 'css', 'sass'` then you can just change it to `'style', 'css!sass'` - Thanks!

Comment: **THIS IS WRONG** read the above comments or answer. Putting this in bold because someone will read this answer and not understand why ExtractTextPlugin is not using all of their loaders.

Comment: Other answers seem to work for others but when I posted the question this is what worked for me so I marked it.

Comment: Worked for me next:
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
            loader: [
               {
                  loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
              }, {
                  loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
              }
            ],
        })