# ReferenceError: window is not defined when using ExtractTextPlugin in Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less, webpack

I'm using `Webpack` to build our project with `ExtractTextPlugin` plugin to separate our CSS into separate files. It works well for most of the CSS/LESS/SASS files within the project except one - vendor.css file that belongs to a 3rd party library. As soon as I include this file into my project, I'm getting **ReferenceError: window is not defined** error message. If I don't use `ExtractTextPlugin` no error messages would appear.

My **webpack.config.js** part of the LESS configuration is below (full file is [here](https://gist.github.com/fruser/df531e9c4e6ee0730e6a)):

```
new ExtractTextPlugin(__dirname + '/Content/js/styles/styles.css'),
...
module: {
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader!' +
      'autoprefixer-loader!' +
      'less-loader'
    )
  }
}
```

Full error message output is [here](https://gist.github.com/fruser/fa1a30ed01f8bdba7223).

Below is my workflow on importing this specific `LESS` file:
Require **styles.js** file, which requires **vendor.less** file, which requires CSS from 3rd party library in Bower directory.

**styles.js**:

```
require('../../../less/vendor.less');
```

**vendor.less**:

```
@import (css) "~vendor-ui-bootstrap/dist/css/arena.css";
```

**arena.css** contains compiled CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223040/window-not-defined-error-when-using-extract-text-webpack-plugin-react ?? Did you try that solution?

Comment: yeah, I'm passing `style-loader` as a separate parameter into the `ExtractTextPlugin` and it works well with other LESS files within the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. The problem was with the `webpack.config.js` file where I had 'jquery' reference in `alias` section:

**webpack.config.js**:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '_': 'underscore',
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}),
...
alias: {
  //'jquery': 'jquery/jquery', - no need to have as I'm using the plugin
  'jquery-bbq': 'jquery-bbq/jquery.ba-bbq',
  'jquery.cookie': 'jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie',
  'jquery.chosen': 'chosen/chosen.jquery.min',
  'jquery.colorpicker': 'jQuery-ColorPicker/colorpicker',
  'jquery.fileupload': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
  'jquery.scrollTo': 'jquery.scrollto/jquery.scrollTo',
  'jquery.tagsinput': 'jquery-tags-input/src/jquery.tagsinput',
  'jquery.tablednd': 'TableDnD/js/jquery.tablednd',
  'jquery.ui': 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
  'jquery.ui.widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget',
  'jquery.validate': 'jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate',
  'json2': 'JSON-js/json2'
},
```

Once I deleted the reference the build process succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I am not using jquery, but some other package was using `window` and it made Jasmine puke.  I cannot modify the package so instead I defined window.

In the file `jasmine.json` put this

```
"helpers": [ "helper.js" ],
```

and in the file `helper.js` put this

```
console.log('===============================');
console.log('=====   BEGIN UNIT TEST   =====');
console.log('===============================');

global.window = {};
```

and now the problem is fixed.