# Why does my webpack configuration stop working when I attempt to use the ExtractTextPlugin?

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

This is my current `webpack.production.config.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src_react/app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style', 'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap'
        )
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules!postcss')
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      'ie': 'component-ie'
    }
  },
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ],
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/src_react/index.tmpl.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[hash].css')
  ]
};
```

This does not work. The following is my `webpack.config.js` file used during development which seems to work fine:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src_react/app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    colors: true,
    inline: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      'ie': 'component-ie'
    }
  },
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ],
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/src_react/index.tmpl.html"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  watch: true
};
```

The main difference between the two files is that the production one attempts to use the `ExtractTextPlugin` but whenever I run the production config with the command `webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js`
 I get errors like the following:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src_react/app/roles/components/job-button/JobButton.scss
    Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../../sass/variables in /Users/Aaron/Documents/src_react/app/roles/components/job-button
     @ ./~/css-loader!./src_react/app/roles/components/job-button/JobButton.scss 3:10-99
```

Why does it try to look for my `_variables.scss` file inside the wrong folder? It works perfectly fine running the development config.

After following Juho's recommendation to change the way I use extract text plugin to `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap')` I get this error instead:

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Comment: Instead of `'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap'` you probably want `'css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap'` too follow `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` API definition.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Hmm. When I do that, I get a whole new error. I've added it to the question above.

Comment: Possibly related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223040/window-not-defined-error-when-using-extract-text-webpack-plugin-react .